# Flex4 Is an object referenced by value or by reference?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

In Actionscript 3 I've read that anything that is not a primative is by reference and primatives are referenced by value. I believe an object is a primative, is it referenced by value?

For instance, if i create

```
//Symbol class (not a primative)
var symbol:Symbol = new Symbol();
symbol.color = 0xFFFFFF;

var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.symbol = symbol 

symbol.color = 0x000000; //change the original symbol color

trace(obj.symbol.color.toString()) //display color of symbol in obj
```

would this return 0xFFFFFF or 0x000000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Primitive" basically means integers or strings. I don't remember off the top of my head if it's both or only integers, but everything else is by reference.

Simple test code you can try running:

```
var spr:Sprite = new Sprite();
var obj:Object = {spr:spr};
var other:Object = {obj:obj};
spr.x = 100;
trace(other.obj.spr.x);
```

That traces 100, not 0.

Comment: > A primitive value is a value that belongs to one of the following data types: Boolean, int, Number, String, and uint.

Comment: Just what i was looking for thanks!.. now i have to figure out where my references to my class are going :P